# How to get a VBA action to work on multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have added this following VBA to a worksheet of mine: the basic premise is to have a diminishing check sheet so the user enters a check total.

If it matches the quantity on the worksheet the cell in column M will show `Validated` and it will automatically hide the line

The issue is that this only works with the first line, subsequent lines don't hide. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("M2").Value = "Validated" Then
        Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("M2").Value = "Re-Check" Then
        Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably mean to use `Target.Row` to know which row is being modified, instead of hard-coding `Rows("2")`.

Comment: Thanks, Target.Row works, however the lines hide regardless of the "Validated" or Re-Check" result. There is obviously an issue with the Range ("M2") part but I'm very new to VBA and I can't work out how to get it to look at the appropriate cell on the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the 3 options bellow (3 different logical constructs)

---

.

**Version 1**

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const CHECK_COL = "M"

    Dim tRow As Long, mVal As String

    tRow = Target.Row
    mVal = LCase(Me.Range(CHECK_COL & tRow).Value2)

    Me.Rows(tRow).Hidden = (mVal = "validated")
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2**

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const CHECK_COL = "M"

    Dim tRow As Long, mVal As String

    tRow = Target.Row
    mVal = LCase(Me.Range(CHECK_COL & tRow).Value2)

    Select Case mVal
        Case "validated":   Me.Rows(tRow).Hidden = True
        Case "re-check":    Me.Rows(tRow).Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 3**

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const CHECK_COL = "M"

    Dim tRow As Long, mVal As String

    tRow = Target.Row
    mVal = LCase(Me.Range(CHECK_COL & tRow).Value2)

    If mVal = "validated" Then
        Me.Rows(tRow).Hidden = True
    ElseIf mVal = "re-check" Then
        Me.Rows(tRow).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```